# how to use magit to edit diff from a commit

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I have committed some changes and in the diff shows some things that they are not necessary.

for example:
    position:relative;
    -  background: whitesmoke; }
    +  background: #f5f5f5; }

So I want to erase this entries. Can I use magit to do this. If not how can be this possible to be done?

Answer (score 5):

You can use <kbd>v</kbd> on the hunk you want to revert, then you can either:

- amend the commit (<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd>) to change the last commit
- just commit, and use <kbd>E</kbd> (interactive-rebase) to squash your revert change with the old commit

If at the beginning the hunk is too big and contain several change,
some of them you want to discard, and other you want to retain, then
you can select the line that you want to discard before using <kbd>v</kbd>

Note the hunk is only a part of the commit, magit will highlight the hunk you currently are on. You can also revert completely the commit by using <kbd>v</kbd> in the header of the commit.

With recent git and magit version, you can also make fixup commit,
then use `git rebase interactive --autosquash` to automatically squash
the fixup commit.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do, in the magit diff hit <kbd>enter</kbd> on the line you want to change it will take you to specific line in the file where you have made the changes. Make your changes then amend the commit by pressing <kbd>c</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd> in the `magit-status-buffer`.